# why is python XML parsing speed inconsistent?

Tags: python, xml, performance, parsing

I am parsing a large (12 GB) XML file made of about 135k more or less similar records (this is an nmap dump). I noticed that the parsing speed is inconsistent, the time to parse similar records changes wildly.

The following scaled-down code outputs the time needed to parse each 1% of the records:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import iterparse
import time
nrhosts = 0
previous = time.time()
context = iterparse("test.xml", events=("start", "end"))
context = iter(context)
event, root = context.next()
for event, elem in context:
    if event == 'end' and elem.tag == "host":
        root.clear()   # clean up memory
        nrhosts += 1
        if nrhosts % 1349 == 0:  # hardcoded to estimate the % as there are ~135k of records
            now = time.time()
            print nrhosts // 1349, now - previous  
            previous = now
```

This gives:

```
1 2.43700003624
2 3.13999986649
3 2.87700009346
4 2.59200000763
5 65.8800001144
6 47.6069998741
7 43.6809999943
8 29.7590000629
9 11.8629999161
10 4.52200007439
11 40.0160000324
12 42.2109999657
13 45.9930000305
14 29.1139998436
15 6.18600010872
16 41.7149999142
17 40.3410000801
18 40.0460000038
19 30.2319998741
20 1.45700001717
21 5.35100007057
22 15.4260001183
23 32.7389998436
24 42.7220001221
25 10.4960000515
26 1.28299999237
27 7.33299994469
28 22.7130000591
29 27.3199999332
30 34.4129998684
31 1.71200013161
32 1.63499999046
33 7.06900000572
34 24.1480000019
35 25.7660000324
36 20.8759999275
37 1.29399991035
38 1.34899997711
39 5.71700000763
40 35.9170000553
41 33.8300001621
42 8.69299983978
43 1.35500001907
44 1.3180000782
45 8.44099998474
46 26.1540000439
47 28.768999815
48 5.91400003433
49 1.63499999046
50 1.30800008774
51 5.93499994278
```

This output seems surprisingly "wavy":

[surprisingly wavy http://i.minus.com/ibiIth8t2AFf4t.png](http://i.minus.com/ibiIth8t2AFf4t.png):

I would like to highlight that:

- the machines on which the code run are quiet (nothing special happens which would disturb the parsing). I have similar results on a laptop running Win7 and on a VM on an ESX running Debian (similar in the sense that the parsing speed changes wildly)
- the records are more or less the same: the XML file is an output from `nmap -O` so the amount of information for each record (a `<host>` in my case) is more or less the same. What I want to say is that there is nothing in the XML output which makes some parts "longer" to parse.

Would anything in my code hint at such behaviour? (I use SAX to handle the size of the XML file, maybe there is something inherent to that which would modify the parsing speed?).

My aim is ultimately to understand whether "this is life" and just accept the fact or modify my code.

Thank you.

Comment: My guess would be that this is how the disk I/O works: the file is read into the buffer in as many chunks as you have peaks on the plot.

Comment: First we should figure out if it's I/O or the actual parsing.  One way to do that: `iterparse(CStringIO.StringIO(open("file.xml").read()))`, that is, read the whole thing into memory first, then parse it.  If that's still erratic, then the parsing or memory (garbage collection?) is probably to blame.

Comment: @John Zwinck: I did that and the results are roughly the same (I tested on a 12GB RAM machine - which is approx. the size of the XML file)

Comment: You should really start monitoring some resources like memory usage, CPU usage, I/O reads and put them next to these statistics. It could be slow I/O, memory swapping, memory defragmentation, simply a harder-to-parse piece of xml, ... .

Comment: Not only IO, but cpu cache misses can affect speed. What are bite sizes of "fast" and "slow" portions of XML? There are tools to monitor advanced usage statistics, such as [Intel Performance Counter http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-performance-counter-monitor-a-better-way-to-measure-cpu-utilization and so on. 

By the way, are you running 64-bit OS or 32b?

Comment: It might be some specific HW related stuff but I did not see any real correlation when monitoring I/O, CPU, etc. Since others do not see this behaviour I guess will have to live with it.

Comment: Maybe try and eliminate garbage collection as a factor : maybe switch it off entirely for your test ? Notes here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html Also - can you generate your test XML programatically (rather than reading off disk) - you might be able to eliminate disk I/O this way (although you might end up with another thing in memory behaving erractically (the generation of XML) that messes up your test...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This graph is almost a fingerprint of the caching system!  :-)
You read the file in chunks (as defined in the ElementTree implementation), but the computer reads much more under the assumption that you will need the next chunks soon. That means that the next chunk you process will need less time, because it is already in memory and so on. However, at a certain moment, the buffer in memory will be almost empty. Exactly at this moment, you will need to "wait" some time for the next chunks to be read, increasing your measurements.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be a silly question, but have you tried using the C implimentation of the XML library?  Try importing

```
from xml.etree.cElementTree import iterparse
```

That should give you a big speed boost.  If it's still not enough I would try using the lxml XML parser http://lxml.de/

Also I'm not sure if its possible to split up the XML file into chunks such that you can utilize multi processing to effectively take advantage of multiple CPU cores, and then merge the results back into a single data structure.

Comment: I tried that as well but the overall behaviour does not really change.

Comment: I've always used the lxml library which tends to have fast consistent performance.  Although any way you parse that large of a file, its going to be slow unless you can split it up into chunks and parse in parallel.   Is there any way you can get a few smaller xml dumps back from nmap, and then use multiprocessing to parse the chunks in parallel?

Comment: the speed is one thing (yes, it is slow :)), what was more surprising is that the rate of processing was not constant. I am not that time-bound so it can take the time it takes, I just noticed an unexpected (at least for me) behaviour.